# How can I stop or fix Wakanda menu highlighting?

Tags: wakanda

Wakanda's Menu Bar widget seems to not have a sense of hierarchy; that is, clicking an item will highlight it and will not un-highlight a clicked item of a different menu item group. Example below:

[image]

"Home" was clicked, and then the submenu item "View Requests" was clicked. "Home" remains highlighted, but it really should have un-highlighted.

It looks sloppy. Do you have any advice for making it nicer?

`event.preventDefault()` on the `onClick` event did not prevent the coloring change for the down state.

Edit: This is all one complex menu bar widget. It has menu bar widgets as submenu items. That's what I mean by a lack of sense of heirarchy. Wakanda fails to see the tree of menu bar widgets as ONE menu bar.

Answer (score 1):

In the properties tab of the Menu Bar widget, change the value of "Show submenus" from  'On Mouse Over' (default) to  'On Mouse Click'.

[image]

Regards.

Comment: Thank you - this is a useful answer. I do like the hover accessibility and ideally I wouldn't sacrifice that to solve the problem, but this is a valid solution.